# Script runs in standalone but does not work in crontab

Tags: shell

Here is the script which works well when executed in standalone but fails when scheduled as a cronjob,

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # TARGET TABLE COUNT FOR Server
 #
CURRENTTARGETREF=$(sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS << END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT CURRENTTARGETREF FROM PARAMETER
exit;
END
)
TABLENAME="TARGET$CURRENTTARGETREF"
TARGETCOUNT=$(sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS << END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TABLENAME
exit;
END
)
echo "Current Target table count in server: $TARGETCOUNT"
#
# COUNTER TABLE COUNT FOR server
#
S1=`echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COUNTER WHERE SERVERID=1;" | sqlplus $DB_USER/$DB_PASS | sed -n '/COUNT(\*)/{n;n;p}'`
S2=`echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COUNTER WHERE SERVERID=2;" | sqlplus $DB_USER/$DB_PASS | sed -n '/COUNT(\*)/{n;n;p}'`
#
echo "Current Counter table count with SERVERID '1' in server:$S1"
echo "Current Counter table count with SERVERID '2' in server:$S2"
#
```

below is the cronjob for this script

```
 31 01 * * * DS=$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d); /path/Databasecount.sh  >> /path/test.out.$DS.txt 2>&1
```

And i wanted to send the output of the script to mail and could you someone please help me on this.

Comment: Does `sqlplus` belong to the PATH as defined in the environment where the crontab script runs? Note that this environment is different from your user environment, e.g. `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` would be ignored.

Comment: i wanted to set the environment variable in script but not sure on how to do it, could you please help me

Comment: You could use full path spec as in `/opt/oracle/product/10.0/bin/sqlplus` instead of `sqlplus` or set up `PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` variables at the beginning of the script as `ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10.0` and `PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin` and `export PATH ORACLE_HOME`. Note that `/opt/oracle/product/10.0` is just an example your path is likely to be different.

Comment: You could also make a symlink from "/opt/...sqlplus" into /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, especially if you have many scripts/cron jobs.

Comment: i am getting the below error    Current Target table count in server: ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | /
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | /
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus